# Jupyter Notebook style in PyCharm

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pycharm

I am working with python notebook in PyCharm. After seeing [this video](https://youtu.be/8-TisZNo_JY?t=264), I updated my professional PyCharm into 2021.3 version.

I opened a new notebook, and got a different UI than the one shown in the video, which looks almost exactly as a Jupyter notebook:

[image: My notebook]

Is there a way to change the style of the notebook so it will look like a Jupyter notebook (like what shown in the video)?
[image: Jupyter notebook]

In addition, when I am running a cell I get the message `Variables are not available` when I am trying to look on the variables. Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to **File>Settings>Color Scheme** and choose something bright.

Below I am showing you the *Classic Light* color scheme
[image]

On the Jupyter part of the question at the bottom part of your screen you should see a **Jupyter** tab [image]

After selecting the tab you should normally see the active variables, as shown below:

[image]